# Pandas df, adding rows between start and end dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My goal is to take one record that has a column for start date and end date. Then create records for each day between both dates.

`df = pd.DataFrame({ 'START_DATE':'8/16/2021' 'END_DATE':'8/28/2021' 'DAYS_BETWEEN':13 'NAME':'LOCATION1' 'TOTAL_AMT':1000})`

The transformed df would have an extra field DATE_VALUE and 13 records representing each day from start date to end date. Besides the DATE_VALUE field all other fields can remain the same in each record.

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: Please provide code to reproduce what you are trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your `df` can have multiple rows and we need to create new records for each day between both dates in each row, we can create a date range record for each row by [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and then expand the date range records to multiple rows (each day in one row) by [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), as follows:

```
df['DATE_VALUE'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['START_DATE'], end=x['END_DATE']), axis=1)

df = df.explode('DATE_VALUE').reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   START_DATE   END_DATE  DAYS_BETWEEN       NAME  TOTAL_AMT DATE_VALUE
0   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-16
1   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-17
2   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-18
3   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-19
4   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-20
5   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-21
6   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-22
7   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-23
8   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-24
9   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-25
10  8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-26
11  8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-27
12  8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-28
```

Comment: I'm getting an error. 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

I tried to upgrade pandas. Then I tried downgrading but it's the same error every time.

Comment: @Tom  What's your version before upgrade ?   Any why downgrade again ?

Comment: I didn't check before I upgraded but the newer version is 1.1.5. 
I'm currently using 1.1.5

Comment: @Tom  So with version 1.1.5 you should be able to use `.explode`, right ?

Comment: I realized that in Jupyter it's running version 0.23.3

Comment: @Tom  So, can you  config with Jupyter to use version 1.1.5 ?   You can't stay on so old version for the long run.

Comment: Yes I'm going to update it. I'll let you know later if it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was able to update Pandas in Jupyter and yes it looks like this worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `df` has only one row like in your example, try:

```
#create a new dataframe with the same row repeated 13 times
df2 = pd.concat([df]*df["DAYS_BETWEEN"].iat[0], ignore_index=True)

#create new column using pd.date_range
df2["DATE_VALUE"] = pd.date_range(df["START_DATE"].iat[0], df["END_DATE"].iat[0], periods=df["DAYS_BETWEEN"].iat[0])

>>> df2
   START_DATE   END_DATE  DAYS_BETWEEN       NAME  TOTAL_AMT DATE_VALUE
0   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-16
1   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-17
2   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-18
3   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-19
4   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-20
5   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-21
6   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-22
7   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-23
8   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-24
9   8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-25
10  8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-26
11  8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-27
12  8/16/2021  8/28/2021            13  LOCATION1       1000 2021-08-28
```

Comment: I like this solution but yes the df has more than one record.
Right now I'm seeing 4 records that I want to turn into 13 records.
Each with different date_value  and the sum of the Total_Amt on all records (1000)

    START_DATE END_DATE DAYS_BETWEEN NAME TOTAL_AMT

8/16/2021 8/28/2021 13 LOCATION1 200

8/16/2021 8/28/2021 13 LOCATION1 200

8/16/2021 8/28/2021 13 LOCATION1 200

8/16/2021 8/28/2021 13 LOCATION1 400

I'm getting a ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
error on the create new column line.

Comment: If you update your question, I could see how to do it over multiple records.